Selection Comment/Uncomment don't work on tsx files in Visual Studio 2022
I'm using Visual Studio 2022 (not Visual Studio Code) to work on a React TypeScript project.
This mostly works, except for one annoyance: when editing files, the Comment/Uncomment Selection actions don't work. Neither the Ctrl+K,Ctrl+C hotkey nor the actual toolbar button. Curiously, Ctrl+K,Ctrl+K works to set a bookmark. This is true for tsx files, but also ts files, where this works fine in other projects. Something about the *.esproj seems to disable a basic editing function.
How can I get these to work properly?
